# Old version of recaptcha get displayed instead of the newer version using the rails gem "Recaptcha"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

Thanks to the gem https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/ (version 0.3.6), I managed to integrate Google Recaptcha into my rails app. The problem is that only the old version (V1) is displayed, similar to below.

[image: V1 recaptcha]

However, I would prefer to the newer version with the checkbox like below, which is much easier for the users. Any idea how to get there?

[image: v1 recaptcha]

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion about this, see: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/112

You are free to implement the new API by yourself it's not that hard actually, and if you have the knowledge submit a pull request to the original repository with a working solution :-)

The instructions on how to implement reCaptcha can be found here: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems that they are quite close to a new release with the newer version.